# The iframe “src” attribute issue

Tags: html

I have make the small iframe  and link to google.com but it is no working 
my code is

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"  src="https://www.google.com.pk/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Errors

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com.pk/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
www.google.com.pk/ Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

Comment: It means what you want to do is not allowed.

Comment: I indented the last line, so that it formats like the error line above it. This makes it easier to read. please see the editing help in the help center for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are entering wrong url. Please refer below code. It may help you.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315"  src="https://www.google.co.pk/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Your url should be: "https://www.google.co.pk".
Yo have entered: https:www.google.com.pk" It is invalid url.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of websites, Google included, block themselves from being displayed in iframes for security reasons.

[See this description for `X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) for how it works